# How to avoid locking when using a static object

Tags: c#, locking

I have a C# desktop application.

In my code I am acquiring an image from a camera. I pass this image to a routine.

This is the 'syntax' of my code:

```
//in a routine
if (!isProcessingMotion)
{
    try
    {
        isProcessingMotion = true;
        //do  stuff
    }
    finally
    {
        isProcessingMotion = false;
    }
}
//////

//module variable:
private static bool isProcessingMotion = false;
```

The function is reached when an event is raised from the parent code.

The trouble is the 'isProcessingMotion = false is not always 'hit'. I have put a try-catch around the whole of the code but there is no error.

I do not want to use monitor or lock('a read only static object') as when I do the app grinds down to a slow process.

What should I be looking out for?

Comment: Surely the real problem is in the code that reads this variable.  If it runs on another thread then, it usually does when you use a camera, then sure, there's trouble.  Don't try so hard to stop doing what you know you need to do, use the lock keyword in whatever code accesses the variable.  Or use a ManualResetEvent instead.

Comment: It seems from your code that you wouldn't want a lock anyway. If it's processing, you want to skip that, not sit and wait until the previous processing finishes. Have you tried Monitor.TryEnter?

Comment: Monitor.TryEnter - seems promising. I wil take alok - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume what is happening is not that the finally block isn't reached, it is that a different thread might be changing the isProcessingMotion variable after that finally block has executed. That might happen when a second event is fired, but the first event hasn't finished processing the first request.

It seems that there are multiple accesses to your field at one.
Although you prefer not to use a lock, this seems like the perfect fix for your problem.
Either that or you'll have to change your application logic to not make multiple reads to that same variable.

### Edit

Since you have to process them sequentially, i'd definitely go with a lock:

```
        var processingLock = new object();
        if (!isProcessingMotion)
        {
            lock (processingLock)
            {
                isProcessingMotion = true;
                // Do stuff..

                isProcessingMotion = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could please explain in more detail what you are trying to do? do the images have to be processed sequentially or could it be done in parallel? why are you depending on the isProcessingMotion?

Comment: They have to be processes sequentially.

Comment: Then using a lock is the way to go.

Comment: Hi, I do not want to use the overhead of using a 'lock' and there IS an overhead using it.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by overhead?

Comment: HI, I wanted to know why my code did not work.  I stated I did not want to use monitor or lock (as in my original question). I just wanted to focus on why the code did not work. I do not have time to go through all my code with you. I have already tried all that you suggested and it gives me a performance hit. I wanted a SPECIFIC focus on why my code did not work not why I think there is an overhead in using locks..  @Hans Passant has given me the closet to helping me to sorting this out.  I need to re-architecture my code.

Comment: Hans gave you exactly the same answer i did, there are multiple places concurrently accessing your code, hence you see that sometimes the value is set to true while it should be false. using the "lock" keyword is syntactical sugar for "Monitor.TryEnter". No need to use caps :)

Comment: Hi, was not using caps to be rude or impatient just to accentuate the point that was important to me. I mean to say @hatchet. Sorry...

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov `lock` and `Monitor.TryEnter` are not the same thing, and each behave differently, and in an important way: one blocks, the other doesn't.

Comment: You're right,  I've mixed between Monitor.Enter with Monitor.TryEnter.